# How do I set a background image for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a bit of a problem. My application is going to use a lot of outside resources for buttons, backgrounds, fields, etc,. The problem is I want it to fit every size phone.

If I have an image 500x500 it won't automatically scale to fit a phone that's say 700x800. What are some common fixes for this type of problem?

EDIT:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_bg_login" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

From the image you really can't see, but it has a border around the image, in any size phone resolution. The blue should be the width of the grey up top.

Comment: please post code what you tried and what is result ?

Comment: how are you setting the background?

Comment: just to make sure, you are `ImageView` to set your background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FrameLayout` add `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"`.

Comment: @DanielContreras Sorry I am not getting you exactly, can you take print screen of the emulator and post the image, so we could see the exactly what's the problem.

Comment: Sorry you were right, I had to remove the image from the ImageView completely. Thank you.